# c# Enumerable.Range with custom scale

Tags: c#, ienumerable, enumerable.range

Hi all I would like to make a system of numbering which can be customized by the user, so for example if the the user inserted Ax with x{0-9} the counter from 1 to 12 would be: A0,A1,A2,A3,..,A9,B0,B1

until now I am obtaining the number to put in the sequence, I order them, take those i want to translate into letters s and use the Enumerable.Range :

```
string hexavigesimal = IntToString(digits[k], Enumerable.Range('A', 26).Select(x => (char)x).ToArray());

 tw.Write("{0}", hexavigesimal);
```

It would be easier if I could make my own scale something like AtoZ000
I think I can obtain that result using Enumerable.Range but I need to make my  own scale, is it possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, so far that sounds possible, but you'll probably need to write some code to do that... What have you tried so far, and where exactly are you stuck? Also some more details on the requirements could help too (for example: are "A" and "x" the only placeholders you need, are there more / other patterns you need to support, etc)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you elaborate, perhaps show some more examples?

Comment: What should happen at `Z9 + 1`? -- I can find arguments for `AA0`, `BA0` and `1A0` depending on the actual logic `Ax` should represent.

Comment: Yeah, what Corak says. You're basically creating a number system with a decimal representation for the last digit and a alphabetic representation for the first digit. What happens when there are three digits, four, twenty seven? You will need to decide how to represent this first then create an overloaded version of the Range linq method that takes the representation as a parameter and start and end positions.

Comment: I'm not sure how using `Enumerable.Range` is going to help here any more than a normal loop `for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)` with some modulus operation (to determine if you need to increment the prefix).

Comment: @Corak, I gave the Ax example to simplify,  at the end of the Range it will start again from the beginning, the final GUI I am preparing has a bigger range and I am inlcuding cases like AAAxxx, xxxAAA, AAxxxxx...

Comment: It would be helpful if you described your cases exactly. How would you increment `AAAxxx`? And at the end of that range (`ZZZ999`) the next item would be `AAA000`?

Comment: How about something like `AxAAxxAxxx`? Or is it always just two parts? -- as an idea, go through the format from right to left and multiply the "mod-number". The "mod-number" of `x` is `10`, the "mod-number" of `A` is `26`. Stop if what you multiplied is bigger than the current number (be smart and store the individual steps, so they don't need to be recalculated for each number). Then go from left to right again and mod the number with the "mod-number" and build a `string` with if `'A'`: `modded-number + 'A'` else `modded-number + '0'` -- might need some off-by-one correction, though...

Answer (score 1):

Approach with `Linq` and no special case treatment

```
int x = 12;
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, x)
                       .Select(c => ((char)('A' + (c / 10))).ToString() + (c % 10))
                       .ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/rB7vO9

Comment: For this specific case (`Ax`; 12 items), yes. But OP seems to want flexibility in declaring different schemes. Also, this will get *weird* if `x` get's big enough to go over `Z9`.

Comment: @Corak, yes it does not solve the problem but it is a start. Now I am trying to expand it to the case AAAxxx